# Short way to make a more IO-like StringIO

Tags: ruby

I want to run something like

```rb
IO.pipe do |readable, writable|
  writable.write "some long text"
  writable.close
  spawn("command", "arg", in: readable)
end
```

Can we turn it into something shorter?

I tried `spawn "command", "arg", in: StringIO.new("text")` but `StringIO` does not implement all the necessary methods to be used as a proper IO object.